# Transforming band matrix to normal

Tags: c#, mathnet-numerics

Is there any way to transform band matrix to normal with [Math.NET Numerics](http://numerics.mathdotnet.com/) library or some other ?

Comment: What do you mean by normal?

Comment: something like [this](https://codeshare.io/6RGR4)

Comment: It's still unclear to me what the relationship between these two matrices is supposed to be. Also, by linear algebra terms, your "Normal matrix" is technically a [band matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Band_matrix), but your "Band matrix" is not.

Comment: I'm sorry, my mistake. I want transforming like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Band_matrix#Band_storage) (from short form to  norma matrix)